# Ubuntu 17.10 netplan to change IP, MAC and name of network card

Tags: networking

I am struggling for hours now to set a fixed IP (sometimes works depending on yaml syntax), the MAC address and the name of my network card.
The yaml file as it stands below, does nothing on reboot.

Please can someone advise on how to achieve these 3 things.
(Yes, I have googled and am now "blue in the face")
Thanks & regards,
Zoltan

```
root@zolpc:/etc/netplan# uname -a
Linux zolpc 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


root@zolpc:/etc/netplan# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:cc:6a:0c:be:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.132/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 85661sec preferred_lft 85661sec
    inet6 fe80::b195:4ae0:5fb8:c253/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever





root@zolpc:/etc/netplan# cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml 

# 
# ip link set eno1 down
# ip link set eno1 address 00:50:da:e2:3d:d8
# ip link set eno1 up
# 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      match: 
        macaddress: 4c:cc:6a:0c:be:87
      addresses: 
        -  192.168.0.142/24
      gateway4:  192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          -  192.168.0.1
          -  8.8.8.8
      set-name: eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to move back to predictable device names like eth0.

To do so I changed **/etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0"
```

then: 
**update-grub** 
and reboot.

After that you should have predictable device names link eht0 and so on.

Now you can edit **/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    lan:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:12:23:45:67:e8
      set-name: lan
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      accept-ra: false
      addresses:
        - 10.10.0.48/24
        - 2b01:2740:7000:cafe::48/64
```

now execute **netplan apply** and it should have worked.

**networkctl list**

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 lan              ether              routable    configured
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check, I have seen where the interface needs to be down before running "netplan apply". In my case I have 16+ interfaces and some were already enabled previously with

```
ip link set dev <interface> up
```

So I found that disabling the interface then running netplan apply worked for me.

```
ip link set dev <interface> down
```

Another helpful addition will be

sudo netplay --debug apply